# Как добавить еще одно условие в PHP-код?

Tags: php

Есть php-код в приложении. Он работает следующим образом. Сервер сверяет полный текущий адрес страницы, сравнивает условие и выводит данные в соответствии с условием. Вопрос: как праильно добавить еще одно условие на другой поддомен? Например, что-то наподобие `(strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'spb.site.ru')`

```
<?php 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'msk.site.ru') !== false) { 
  echo '1111'; 
} else {
  echo '2222';
}
?>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите.  `switch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'msk.site.ru') !== false){ 
        echo '1111'; 
    } else if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'spb.site.ru') !== false) {
        echo '3333';
    } else {
        echo '2222';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Не приложу ума, почему возникает в ответ на код ошибка `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

Comment: @QuickBrownFox  `} else if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'spb.site.ru' !== false) {` скобка у `strpos` не закрыта, сразу после `false`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]